# Count strings ocurrences in one field result - Oracle 11

Tags: oracle11g, aggregate

What I want is to count strings ocurrences in this way:

```
ID | NAME | ITEMS
1  | JFK  | 100/100/100/200/300/300
```

I want to turn it into

```
ID | NAME | ITEMS
1  | JFK  | 100(3),200(1),300(2)
```

A function will be fine, but if you can do within a SELECT will be awesome.

I am using Oracle 11, but if you can provide generic may help more people.

Thanks :)

Comment: What if they aren't  ordered that neatly - what would you expect to see for e.g. `100/300/100/200/100`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long-winded, but you can tokenize your strings into separate rows:

```
select id, name, regexp_substr(items, '(.*?)(/|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as item
from your_table
connect by level < regexp_count(items, '(.*?)(/|$)')
and prior id = id
and prior dbms_random.value is not null;
```

and then group by item to get the counts:

```
select id, name, item, count(*) as item_count
from (
  select id, name, regexp_substr(items, '(.*?)(/|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as item
  from your_table
  connect by level < regexp_count(items, '(.*?)(/|$)')
  and prior id = id
  and prior dbms_random.value is not null
)
group by id, name, item;
```

and then group again by just ID and name to aggregate back to a single string:

```
select id, name,
  listagg(item || '(' || item_count || ')', '/') within group (order by item) as items
from (
  select id, name, item, count(*) as item_count
  from (
    select id, name, regexp_substr(items, '(.*?)(/|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as item
    from your_table
    connect by level < regexp_count(items, '(.*?)(/|$)')
    and prior id = id
    and prior dbms_random.value is not null
  )
  group by id, name, item
)
group by id, name
order by id;
```

With your example and another one in a different order provided via a CTE:

```
with your_table (id, name, items) as (
            select 1, 'JFK', '100/100/100/200/300/300' from dual
  union all select 2, 'LBJ', '100/300/100/200/100' from dual
)
select ...
```

that query gets

```
        ID NAM ITEMS                                             
---------- --- --------------------------------------------------
         1 JFK 100(3)/200(1)/300(2)                              
         2 LBJ 100(3)/200(1)/300(1)
```